# Install on Websphere 7.0.0.37/Oracle 11.2.0.1 fails

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have sucessfully deployed MobileFrist and MaximoAnywhere to Websphere 8.5 and Oracle 11.2.0.1 (using the Anywhere.war)

After deploying to Websphere 7.0.0.37 and Oracle 11.2.0.1 and the Anywhere-2.4.war) when I try to log in I get the error ...
The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

On the client log there is

```
an errorFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
Logger.js:202 Cancel processing requested
dojo.js:2 klass "
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at Object.WL.Client.invokeProcedure.onFailure (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:359:25)
    at Object.options.onFailure (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:8632:29)
    at Object.onInvokeProcedureFailure [as onFailure] (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:8544:14)
    at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onFailure (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:3577:26)
    at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlFailure (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:3529:12)
    at http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:958:20
    at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:1184:28)
    at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:1117:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:958:20)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at Promise.then._7cd.then (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:275189)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:76:4)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:860:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161)
    at Function.on.emit (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:557950)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:126:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:599634)"
```

On the server I get the following error

```
[10/1/15 12:11:28:025 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/init
[10/1/15 12:11:28:565 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/header_disconnected.png
[10/1/15 12:11:29:618 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/header_app_noBack.png
[10/1/15 12:11:29:624 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/header_overflow_OFF.png
[10/1/15 12:11:29:642 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/header_back_OFF.png
[10/1/15 12:11:29:684 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/header_split_cancel_OFF.png
[10/1/15 12:11:30:830 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/loguploader
[10/1/15 12:11:30:836 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/loguploader
[10/1/15 12:11:30:922 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/ibmLogoDark.png
[10/1/15 12:11:30:973 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/images/mdpi/status_error.png
[10/1/15 12:11:36:453 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query
[10/1/15 12:11:36:454 BST] 0000003e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query
[10/1/15 12:11:36:455 BST] 0000003e ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet GadgetAPIServlet in application IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_MaximoAnywhereMobileFirst. Exception created : com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:604)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:469)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:443)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:440)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:140)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)

[10/1/15 12:11:36:456 BST] 0000003e Authenticatio E com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter doFilter FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:172)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:604)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:469)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:443)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:440)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:140)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    ... 27 more
 [project MaximoAnywhere]
                                 com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:172)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:604)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:469)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:443)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:440)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:140)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    ... 27 more

[10/1/15 12:11:36:466 BST] 0000003e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[GadgetAPIServlet]: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:172)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:604)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:469)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:443)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:440)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:140)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    ... 27 more
```

Any suggestions, or has anyone sucessfully managed to deploy to this arrangement.

Thanks,

Keith

Comment: Just an update on this ... I can successfully deploy on Apache/MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug with WebSphere 7 and Worklight.  There's a web module setting that has to be applied to prevent these 500 exceptions from being propagated down to the worklight engine.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM74090

Comment: I was already on 7.0.0.37, I just needed to add the custom property to the Webcontainer, restart and this solved my problem.